# Options in tables with data from database

Tags: php

This is a tough one to explain...

I'm developing a restaurant system where the user add the dishes available to sell, but the user has to have an option to edit/delete AFTER the dish was registered.

So what i thought was: k, gonna make a table fetching the data from the DB and in the last column put some options like edit/delete... Here is the code for better understanding:

```
foreach ($result as $row){                 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.'<img src="img/icons/16/delete.png" alt="delete" height="16" width="16">'.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';             
 }
```

Like you've saw the delete option has already there (with no function/action yet) Here is the thing... I could put a link to a file in href="delete.php? but when a user clicks on this link will lead them to the delete.php page, leaving the administration page... I would like that when the user clicks the delete img, worked as/similar AJAX. I don't want the user exit the page....

Sorry for bad english (not my mothertongue), if you guys want more details just ask.
Ps: New PHP Programmer
Thanks in advance.

Comment: be very very VERY VERY careful putting in clickable links that can delete things: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript or jQuery to do an ajax request to delete.php with the id of the row you want to delete. I often put the id in the `<tr>` like `echo "<tr data-id='{$row['id']}'>"` and my jQuery would look something like this

```
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
  var id= $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
  $.ajax({
    url:"delete.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{id:id},
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      // do something with the data returned. I usually output "success" from my 
      // delete.php and then check for data.indexOf('success') != -1
      $("tr[data-id="+id+"]").remove();
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: "+jqXHR+" "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

on my delete.php page i check that `$_POST['id']` is not empty before continuing. If you use `$_REQUEST['id']` it will also work with a direct link to `delete.php?id=999`

Comment: All works fine, but the
$("tr[data-id='+id+']").remove();
part doesn't... this should remove the <tr> tag right? i've put an alert('hi'); just to see if the ajax file was loaded...

Comment: The single quotes should have been double quotes. `$("tr[data-id="+id+"]").remove();` I have updated my answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Delete.php using AJAX, so the request is executed without leaving the page.

The advantage of making an actual link to the delete page, is that it also works without Ajax/Javascript. So you can start by building a plain delete page, and add the Ajax later.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should also print a record_id because just deleting based on the name is a very bad idea where encoding will hunt you down.

Having said that, here is what I would do using jQuery:

```
//PHP
foreach ($result as $row){                 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.'<img class="delete-btn" src="img/icons/16/delete.png" alt="delete" height="16" width="16" data-order-id="$row['id']">'.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';             
 }    


//JQUERY
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete-btn").click(function(){
        $.post("/delete.php", {order_id: $(this).attr("data-order-id")}, function(){
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
    });
});
```